# Counting the number of labels in a scatter plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scatter-plot

I have three scatter plots that compare between two numeric continuous columns, in three cancer types. Each row of the two columns belongs to a cancer type.

Here is a small subset of the data:

```
structure(list(cancer_type = c("Renal Cell Carcinoma", "Melanoma", 
"Renal Cell Carcinoma", "Renal Cell Carcinoma", "Melanoma", "Renal Cell Carcinoma", 
"Melanoma", "Renal Cell Carcinoma", "Melanoma", "Renal Cell Carcinoma", 
"Renal Cell Carcinoma", "Renal Cell Carcinoma", "Melanoma", "Renal Cell Carcinoma", 
"Renal Cell Carcinoma", "Renal Cell Carcinoma", "Melanoma", "Renal Cell Carcinoma", 
"Renal Cell Carcinoma", "Renal Cell Carcinoma", "Melanoma", "Renal Cell Carcinoma", 
"Renal Cell Carcinoma", "Renal Cell Carcinoma", "Renal Cell Carcinoma", 
"Urothelial Carcinoma", "Urothelial Carcinoma", "Urothelial Carcinoma", 
"Urothelial Carcinoma", "Urothelial Carcinoma", "Urothelial Carcinoma", 
"Urothelial Carcinoma", "Urothelial Carcinoma", "Urothelial Carcinoma", 
"Urothelial Carcinoma", "Urothelial Carcinoma"), Model1 = c(0.144175127148628, 
0.145591989159584, 0.0984272509813309, 0.0906868129968643, 0.28544145822525, 
0.138114541769028, 0.091837003827095, 0.0904595032334328, 0.211963757872581, 
0.163982316851616, 0.0935302376747131, 0.127466395497322, 0.117602989077568, 
0.18533518910408, 0.0753359571099281, 0.157020777463913, 0.211388036608696, 
0.0914847329258919, 0.177859485149384, 0.137649402022362, 0.240238919854164, 
0.10163140296936, 0.128856286406517, 0.1811293810606, 0.145569115877151, 
0.108640238642693, 0.157251104712486, 0.141889616847038, 0.0737133473157883, 
0.140953287482262, 0.196182891726494, 0.135421812534332, 0.174105599522591, 
0.0961336940526962, 0.0573264583945274, 0.0880825147032738), 
    Model2 = c(0.314525783061981, 0.343217849731445, 0.315391361713409, 
    0.353350460529327, 0.562197327613831, 0.292534917593002, 
    0.616392850875854, 0.284660279750824, 0.532478809356689, 
    0.341239869594574, 0.35737070441246, 0.31985279917717, 0.619661331176758, 
    0.224026560783386, 0.268743008375168, 0.344117254018784, 
    0.542939126491547, 0.267527014017105, 0.2816281914711, 0.443801760673523, 
    0.552633106708527, 0.387285768985748, 0.186705753207207, 
    0.234086975455284, 0.287418365478516, 0.564366817474365, 
    0.392496168613434, 0.642540812492371, 0.688632488250732, 
    0.430574655532837, 0.360769122838974, 0.58690744638443, 0.510010659694672, 
    0.559859037399292, 0.665197253227234, 0.460800766944885), 
    stage = c("STAGE1", "STAGE1", "STAGE2", "STAGE4", "STAGE4", 
    "STAGE4", "STAGE3", "STAGE3", "STAGE1", "STAGE2", "STAGE2", 
    "STAGE1", "STAGE1", "STAGE3", "STAGE4", "STAGE1", "STAGE1", 
    "STAGE1", "STAGE1", "STAGE3", "STAGE2", "STAGE4", "STAGE4", 
    "STAGE1", "STAGE1", "STAGE1", "STAGE2", "STAGE4", "STAGE3", 
    "STAGE3", "STAGE2", "STAGE1", "STAGE1", "STAGE4", "STAGE3", 
    "STAGE2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("04d83340b8bd", 
"122T", "1c2a5ac94492", "1d209304d988", "212T", "24ab7fecc92e", 
"356T", "379fe8924c51", "39T", "3ec4d3fc8bd1", "3f78044299b5", 
"4260f878a482", "430T", "43b757f285d8", "49c4c0e12e32", "55cc6edfad7f", 
"62T", "689be0421d3c", "8237266761ca", "85d99ff60fa1", "9T", 
"a4d25b70d77c", "a74ac0179106", "ac07fd7297c8", "c0f7a7b642cd", 
"SAM3cb94b0d5297", "SAM47fc46c3d6be", "SAM4b0175e8db6e", "SAM4b7ea015fd9e", 
"SAM553c3c35b847", "SAM560f23d6a3ad", "SAM5c139c5c1c4f", "SAM5cc2d9036053", 
"SAM5cfa1699bdb7", "SAM5d989c86255e", "SAM6157c8f38b72"))
```

As you see in each plot there are a horizontal and a vertical lines. I can adjust the position of those line as I please of course.

[image]

There are three colors: yellow, bluew and grey. I need the number of each color in each quarter.

For example - The melanoma plot, the down quarter to the right has only 1 yellow dot. The upper left has two yellow, 1 blue and 1 grey. In my real data there is much, much more dots, this is just a small example.

I need this numbering for each quarter for each plot. How can I do that?

This is the code that made the plot, you can adjust it if needed:

```
scatterplot_for_models= function(data = data, Model_1 = Model_1, Model_2 = Model_2, x = x, y = y){
        
  ggplot(data,aes(1-data[[Model_2]], data[[Model_1]], fill=stage)) +
    geom_point(size=4,pch=21) + theme_classic()+
    facet_wrap(.~cancer_type)+
    scale_fill_manual(values=c('#E69F00', '#56B4E9','#999999','#999999')) +
    xlab("Model 2") + ylab("Model 1") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = y,linetype=2)+
    geom_vline(xintercept = x,linetype=2)
  
  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is rather straight forward as long as you don't try to do this within ggplot. Do a couple of data summaries beforehand and use those for plotting. In this case, I think the most straight forward is to first define the coordinates for label plotting, then count the points per quadrant (you will need to decide where to place points that "tie".

```r
library(tidyverse)

## assuming you know your cut off values
y_cut <- .16
x_cut <- .5
## basic data frame modificiation for easier coding
data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    x = 1 - Model2,
    y = Model1
  )
## first, get the label positions.
## We will define the quadrants clockwisefrom top right to top left
label_pos <-
  data %>%
  summarise(
    x_right = mean(c(x_cut, max(x))),
    x_left = mean(c(x_cut, min(x))),
    y_top = mean(c(y_cut, max(y))),
    y_bottom = mean(c(y_cut, min(y)))
  )
label_coord <- 
  data.frame(matrix(unlist(c(rep(label_pos[1:2], each = 2), c(label_pos[3:4], label_pos[4:3]))), nrow = 4))
names(label_coord) <- c("x_lab", "y_lab")
## now, summarise how many dots are per quadrant based on those cut offs
## and add the label positions
data_count <- data %>%
  mutate(quad = case_when(
    x > x_cut & y > y_cut ~ "quad1",
    x > x_cut & y < y_cut ~ "quad2",
    x < x_cut & y < y_cut ~ "quad3",
    x < x_cut & y > y_cut ~ "quad4"),
    ## convert both groups to factors
    cancer_type = as.factor(cancer_type), 
    quad = as.factor(quad)
  ) %>%
  count(cancer_type, quad, .drop = FALSE)
## now merge both
data_annot <- data_count %>%
  bind_cols(label_coord[rep(1:nrow(label_coord), 3), ])
## do the data transformation before
ggplot(mapping = aes(x, Model1)) +
  geom_point(data = data, aes(fill = stage), size = 4, pch = 21) +
  ## now you can simply use geom_text for annotation
  geom_text(data = data_annot, mapping = aes(x_lab, y_lab, label = paste("n=", n))) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ cancer_type) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#999999", "#999999")) +
  xlab("Model 2") +
  ylab("Model 1") +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = y_cut, linetype = 2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = x_cut, linetype = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Can this code specify how many dots are there from each color? your output presents the number of dots overall for each quarter without referring to the colors, right?

Comment: @ProgrammingNoob I'll leave this to you to adjust my example to a further group. Although I don't recommend this for the plot, as too much labelling will just over-crowd the graph. I'd suggest to use a table instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the data as processed by ggplot up to rendering the actual plot by extracting `data` from the output of `ggplot_build(p)` where `p` is the result of a former `ggplot` run. Example:

```
ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]
```

This data is easy tabulated, e.g. with {dplyr}, using your example data:

```
x_intercept = .5
y_intercept = .16

p <-  df |> ## save ggplot object as "p"
  ggplot(aes(1 - Model2, Model1, fill=stage)) +
  geom_point(size=4,pch=21) + theme_classic()+
  facet_wrap( ~ cancer_type)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#E69F00', '#56B4E9','#999999','#999999')) +
  xlab("Model 1") + ylab("Model 2") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = y_intercept, linetype=2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = x_intercept, linetype=2)
```

```
p ## display ggplot
```

tabulate ggplot data:

```
library(dplyr)

ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]] |>
                count(PANEL, ## the facet_wrap panel index (~ cancer_type)
                      fill, ## the fill (~ stage)
                      x > x_intercept, 
                      y > y_intercept
                      )
```

output (truncated):

```
+    PANEL    fill x > x_intercept y > y_intercept n
1      1 #56B4E9           FALSE            TRUE 1
2      1 #999999           FALSE           FALSE 1
3      1 #999999           FALSE            TRUE 1
4      1 #E69F00           FALSE           FALSE 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case_when()` to define the quadrant into which each point falls, and then use `count()`, grouping by `stage` and `cancer_type`

```
x=0.5
y=0.16
df %>% mutate(q = case_when(
  Model2<x & Model1>y~"ul",
  Model2>=x & Model1>y~"ur",
  Model2<x & Model1<=y~"ll",
  Model2>=x & Model1<=y~"lr",
)) %>% count(stage,cancer_type,q)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a another suggestion using `ggrepel`: Note `df` is the original data frame and `df1` is the one for labeling only:

How it works:

**1. Create a data frame for labeling purposes only. Note we have to eliminate all duplicates!**

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(helper_x = ifelse(Model2 <= 0.5, "a", "b"),
         helper_y = ifelse(Model1 <= 0.16, "a", "b")) %>% 
  group_by(cancer_type, helper_x, helper_y) %>% 
  arrange(.by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  add_count(stage) %>% 
  mutate(label = paste(stage, "N=", n, sep=" ")) %>% 
  group_by(cancer_type, helper_x, helper_y, stage) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

**2. Plot and label:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=1-Model2, y=Model1, color=stage))+
  geom_point(size=4, alpha=0.8)+
  facet_wrap(.~cancer_type)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#999999", "#999999")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0.5, linetype = "longdash")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.16, linetype = "longdash")+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_label_repel(data=df1, aes(label = label),
                   box.padding   = 0.35, 
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = 'grey50',
                   show.legend = FALSE) +
  xlab("Model2")
```

[image]

Comment: That's quite neat. I especially like your use of `ifelse` +1